# Where does console output go when Eclipse PyUnit Test Runner configured to use Nose

Tags: python, eclipse, nose, python-unittest

I'm using Eclipse / PyDev and PyUnit on OSX for development. It was recommended to me that I use Nose to execute our suite of tests.

When I configure Nose as the test runner, however, output from the interactive console (either standalone or during debugging) disappears. I can type commands but do not see any output.

Is this normal, or am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found in the Preferences > PyDev > PyUnit menu that adding -s to the Parameters for test running stopped this. The parameter prevents the capture of stdout that nose does by default.

The alternate --nocapture parameter should work too.